# Code highlight in Pycharm: remove green background after back-ticks

Tags: pycharm, syntax-highlighting

I have this annoying green backgroud after `template` and `styles`. And I really don't understand how to get rid of it. I haven't found any option connected to this back-ticks and there are no help pop-ups also.

How to get rid of this? Anybody knows?
 [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!
Preferences > Editor > Colors & Fonts > General
Code > Injected language fragment
Turn off background.

Answer (score 4):

I have the green highlight issue comparing duplicate code. Finally found the solution is pressing **esc**.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

I think you can't, that's the fun of the theme.